# On NP and PP in RP?

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes

Does $NP\subseteq RP\implies NP=RP$?

Does $PP\subseteq RP\implies \oplus P=NP=RP$?

At least what additional minimal conditions will give truth of above?

Comment: Try writing down the definitions of those classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see why the first implication holds, note that you can use the sequence of coin tosses as a witness (if the input is not in the language, no accepting sequence exists).

As for the second implication, note that $\mathsf{\oplus P\subseteq P^{PP}}$, since you can find the exact number of accepting paths using binary search. If $\mathsf{PP=RP}$, then $\mathsf{\oplus P\subseteq P^{RP}}$. Since $\mathsf{PP}$ is closed under complement, you have $\mathsf{RP=coRP=ZPP}$, which means $\mathsf{\oplus P\subseteq P^{ZPP}\subseteq RP}$. I doubt that you can show $\mathsf{RP\subseteq \oplus P}$ in this case, since relativizing techniques won't do here. In ["NP Might Not Be As Easy As Detecting Unique Solutions"](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~fortnow/papers/newiso.pdf) by Beigel et al. they construct an oracle relative to which $\mathsf{ZPP=EXP}$ (implying $\mathsf{PP=RP}$) and $\mathsf{P = \oplus P}$, which means $\mathsf{RP\nsubseteq \oplus P}$.